# Query with multiple arguments in laravel with foregin key

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I would like my search engine to return values after searching by more than one argument. Currently my search engine works like this:

query->sample city->all records with this city

What can be done to make it work like this

query->sample city and sample street->all records with this city and street

laravel 10 (without laravel scout)
php 8.2

code:

```
public function search(Request $request){
        
        $search = $request->search;

        $resorts = Resort::where(function($query) use ($search){
            // query to main table
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('street', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('home_number', 'like', "%$search%");
            
            //->orWhere('description' 'like', "%$search%"); 
        })
        //query with foreign key
        ->orWhereHas('voivodeship',function($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
        })
        ->get();

        return view('index',compact('resorts', 'search'));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

search in the closure function

```php
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%$search%')
        ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('street', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('home_number', 'like', "%$search%");
})
```